# yum install ends with "already installed and latest version" whereas "pip -V" shows "No such file or directory"

Tags: installation, pip, redhat, yum

sudo yum install python-pip
 on this Redhat Linux 6 server ends with -

```
Trying other mirror.
epel                                                                                                                                                                                                                   | 5.3 kB     00:00     
http://fedora.westmancom.com/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml does not match metalink for epel
Trying other mirror.
Setting up Install Process
Package python-pip-7.1.0-1.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

And trying to see version -

```
$ pip -V
-bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

Comment: maybe someone removed the binaries? You can check the integrity of an installed package using `rpm -V python-pip` . Suppose someone messed with the installed files, you could `yum reinstall python-pip`

Comment: reinstall resolved this. You may add it as answer.

Comment: I have added this as an answer. happy to help.

Comment: @ChrisMaes Thanks. Please check if you can answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496026/all-python-and-pip-commands-throwing-syntax-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe someone removed the binaries? You can check the integrity of an installed package using

```
rpm -V python-pip
```

Suppose someone messed with the installed files, you could

```
yum reinstall python-pip
```